# Solving VRPTW using OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I have tried to run example https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting 
as it is written here:
 http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#downloadAndRunTheExamples with data set cvrptw-25customers.xml . When I changed readyTime and dueTime in some customers, it didn't result in any change in score. It looks like this program doesn't care about time windows. Should I change something in Java classes? My goal is to get time needed to drive to all customers, taking into account all time windows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I 've done it several times myself. Potential causes:

- Did you load the xml file again? Try changing the VehicleRoutingPanel code so it's obvious which customer you changed and if indeed the values changed. Compare the screenshot of before and after your change (or duplicate the xml file so you keep the original).
- If some arrival times and dueTimes change, the score doesn't need to change. Try making very small time windows, at annoying times, that should definitely impact the score and make it worse.